# Do Async Web service calls keep the connection alive?

Tags: c#, web-services

A very quick question came to mind that whether the async web service calls keeps the connection alive?
If not then what is the underlying mechanism to reconnect to client via callback function after the operation is performed.
If yes then is it just the perception for the client that they can move forward without waiting for the response from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async method spawns a thread to wait for the response from the service.  It would be the same as if you called the webservice from a background thread.  The connection is still open, the channel is still listening and waiting for a response.

Think of the async webservice call as an invoke across a boundary.